# Is there a way to determine at runtime, in GHC, whether an abstract value is a function?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I wonder if it's possible to have a function (somewhat similar to [`dataToTag#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.4.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#v:dataToTag-35-)) like:

```
isFunction# :: a -> Bool
```

or likely equivalently:

```
isFunction# :: Any -> Bool
```

which returns `True` iff the value passed in as an argument is of a type `a -> b` (or, for that matter, `a => b`) at runtime for some types `a` and `b`, or a `newtype` whose underlying type is (so it "sees through" `newtype`s, but of course not `data`), without forcing its argument. I didn't see anything like this in [GHC.Prim](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.4.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html) myself, but I may have missed something, or maybe it's possible with a manual CMM primop or something.

Now that the question has occurred to me I'm curious about the answer for its own sake ([question Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), but the original reason it occurred to me (question X) is that the complaint usually levelled against `seq` is that it breaks eta equivalence by making it possible to observe the difference between `undefined` and `\_ -> undefined`, and I was wondering if it would be possible to make a version of `seq` (`myseq a = if isFunction# a then flip const a else seq a`) that's still "magically polymorphic" (works `forall a`), but simply leaves functions alone.

Comment: How is `a => b` a function type?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: it actually is. `=>` is desugared to `->` in GHC Core.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs (A.K.A. dictionary passing.)

Comment: I realize that typeclasses are implemented using dictionary passing, but it is just that: an implementation detail that the design of typeclasses is intended to hide. I wouldn't consider a value of type `a => b` to be a function *in Haskell*. It would be strange if a hypothetical `isFunction#` predicate returned `True` for such a type.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: the issue is that we can't possibly distinguish `=>` from `->` once we try to look at runtime objects.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Ah, good point. That would make such a function impossible if you want it to give what I would consider to be correct results.

Comment: My (mildly educated) guess is that this is not possible in general. Is `mempty` a function? What about `mempty @()`? `mempty @(Endo ())`? In GHC, the latter two are both closures over identical code blocks; how are you planning to distinguish them?

Comment: For example, the `a => b` case would imply that `1` is a function. I think this would be an unexpected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, surely not. How could it know without evaluating the argument?

But to address your question X directly, your proposed `myseq` is worse than the real `seq` since it breaks parametricity. Is `myseq undefined :: b -> b` bottom, or the identity? It depends on whether the type variable `a` (`undefined :: a`) was instantiated with a function type or not.

In Haskell you are always allowed to drop a `forall a.` when `a` does not appear in the type at all, thanks to parametricity: the choice of `a` cannot matter. Your `myseq` would lose that property.

This is also why you could not implement `isFunction#` without annotating values at runtime with their intended types (`isFunction# undefined` is similarly meaningless).

Comment: `seq` itself breaks parametricity.

Comment: Well, words are fuzzy. It doesn't break the same feature that `myseq` would.

Comment: More specifically, I think it's consistent with the idea of parametricity that all the types you can quantify over support some common operations. Then you will get correspondingly weaker guarantees from parametricity. But if you can write expressions of type `forall a. Int` whose value depends on the choice of the type `a`, then you have no form of parametricity at all.